# Why do promises and async/await resolve promises in different orders?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

From everything I've read, async/await is just syntactic sugar for promises. From this, I would expect the following two functions to work the same, assuming `promise_1` and `promise_2` are both promises:

```
function promises(promise_1, promise_2) {
    promise_1.then((val) => {
        console.log(val);
        promise_2.then((val2) => {
            console.log(val2);
        });
    });
}
async function asyncawait(promise_1, promise_2) {
    console.log(await promise_1);
    console.log(await promise_2);
}
```

However, when testing them I've noticed that the `promises` function resolves the second promise earlier than the async function:

```
let func;
async function test() {
    let promise_1 = Promise.resolve("first");
    let promise_2 = Promise.resolve("second");

    func(promise_1, promise_2);

    console.log("await first");
    await promise_1;
    console.log("awaited first");

    console.log("await second");
    await promise_2
    console.log("awaited second");
}
```

Running

```
func = promises;
test();
```

Produces the following output:

```
await first
first
second
awaited first
await second
awaited second
```

Note how after awaiting `promise_1`, both `promise_1` and `promise_2` resolved.

However, running

```
func = asyncawait;
test();
```

Produces the following (expected) output:

```
await first
first 
awaited first
await second
second
awaited second
```

With the promise resolutions interleaved.

What's causing this difference in resolution order to occur?

Comment: in chrome 76.0.3809.100 both functions produces same output. this test makes no sense, both promises are already resolved before awaits, it's a race condition which await will finish sooner. Why do you expect one await to unblock the other?

Comment: Can't repro: https://jsfiddle.net/bxshwe2t/

Comment: Interesting, this is consistent in both my node testing environment and firefox for me. Guess it's just browser weirdness. 
Second behavior is expected because although they're both resolved, once test() returns, only the first promise has any then() handlers attached. I would expect both of those to resolve before any new then()s created resolve (as in, have a FIFO queue for resolutions)

Comment: Are you using something like Babel, TypeScript or some other code transpiler? It's plausible the generated code is not correct.

Comment: Yes, using TypeScript for Node, but I'm getting this behavior in Firefox console directly, so no transpiling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you correctly stated "async/await is just syntactic sugar for promises." Consider this,

```
function foo(flag){
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if(flag) res("Resolved");
      else rej("Rejected")
    },1000);
  })
}
```

*The key here is async function always returns a promise.* see [return value of a async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Return_value)

Now, lets use this function,

```
function useFoo(){
  return foo(true).then(val => { console.log(val); return val; })
                  .catch(err => { console.log(err); throw err; })
}
```

this is equivalent to,

```
async function useFoo(){
  try{
    const val = await foo(false);
    console.log(val);
    return val;
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Explanation of your behaviour,

```
(function(){
  foo(1).then((x)=> console.log(x)); 
  console.log("after foo()");
})()
```

Using the same foo function, above code snippet logs `after foo()` before anything else since foo() is an asynchronous function. for synchronous operation on the executor function, it is executed immediately.,

This is how "async/await is just syntactic sugar for promises"

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not seeing how this explains my behavior. My test function itself is marked async, and the after print statements are right after await statements.

Comment: @fuzzything44 the last snippet explains the behaviour of your first test, ie test=promises,

Comment: the first print is in the .then() of the first promise, and the second print is in the .then() of the second. Your example has printing after the .then() handler is added, but outside it. This doesn't explain the first test.